# Wordpress plugin web form

Tags: html, wordpress

I want to create a wordpress plugin. That plugin contains a simple html form and some javascript. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ for all Wordpress related questions

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest way to create plugin

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Coding friends hello world
Plugin URI: http://www.codingfriends.com/
Description: Outputs hello world
Version: 0.1
Author: Genux
Author URI: http://www.codingfriends.com
License: GPL2
*/

function codingfriends_helloworld()
{
    //put you form here and javascript here
}

add_action('get_header', 'codingfriends_helloworld');
?>
```